# ivy:resolve removing confs from descriptor

Tags: ivy, artifactory

I have a utilities project which I build using Ivy & Ant and publish to Artifactory:

**ivy.xml for utils project:**

```
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
            version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.abc" module="utils"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="%->default,sources">
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="sources"/>
        <conf name="compile-main" extends="default" visibility="private" transitive="false"/>
        <conf name="compile-test" extends="compile-main" visibility="private" transitive="false"/>
        <conf name="run-test" extends="compile-test" visibility="private" transitive="true"/>
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="utils" type="jar"/>
        <artifact name="utils-src" type="source" ext="zip" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
        <--snip... -->
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

This works fine. I can see the JAR, the `-sources.zip` and the Ivy descriptor getting published to Artifactory just fine.

I then try and use this JAR in a dependent project:

**ivy.xml for dependent project:**

```
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
            version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.abc" module="dependent"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="%->default,sources">
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="compile-main" extends="default" visibility="private" transitive="false"/>
        <conf name="compile-test" extends="compile-main" visibility="private" transitive="false"/>
        <conf name="run-test" extends="compile-test" visibility="private" transitive="true"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies> 
        <dependency org="org.abc" name="utils" rev="latest.integration" conf="default"/> 
        <!-- snip... -->
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

If I change the `defaultconfmapping` for the dependent project to `%->default`, everything works fine. When I set the `defaultconfmapping` to `%->default,sources`, sources for other dependencies (JUnit, log4j, etc.) get downloaded fine, but I get an error for the sources of my utils project:

```
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.abc#utils;20120611153645: configuration not found in org.abc#utils;20120611153645: 'sources'. It was required from org.abc#dependent;working@blah.abc.org default
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What's interesting is that if I look inside the Ivy cache, the Ivy XML file looks like this:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.abc"
            module="utils"
            revision="20120611153645"
            status="release"
            publication="20120611154459"
            default="true"
    />
    <configurations>
            <conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
            <artifact name="utils" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="default"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

So, for some reason Ivy has decided to remove all the private confs (makes sense) + the sources conf + the sources artifact from the descriptor during the resolve process. I cannot for the life of me understand why. I can see the XML file is fine in Artifactory - exactly as I wrote it. So why is Ivy ditching the sources information when it resolves it?

For reference, here's the early part of my Ant script:

```
<ivy:configure url="http://repo:8081/artifactory/simple/bootstrap-local/ivysettings.xml"/>
<ivy:resolve log="downloadOnly"/>
<fail message="Go check out the cache file now"/> <!-- added to find out whether resolve or retrieve broke it -->
```

Confused!

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps this working example will help...

## Test

```
|-- proj1
|   |-- build.xml
|   `-- ivy.xml
`-- proj2
    |-- build.xml
    `-- ivy.xml
```

After running the builds as follows

```
ant -f ./proj1/build.xml
ant -f ./proj2/build.xml
```

Have the following file structure

```
|-- proj1
|   |-- build
|   |   |-- ivy.xml
|   |   |-- utils.jar
|   |   `-- utils-src.zip
|   |-- build.xml
|   `-- ivy.xml
`-- proj2
    |-- build.xml
    |-- ivy.xml
    `-- lib
        `-- utils-20120612011906.jar
```

### proj1

build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="init">
        <echo file="build/utils.jar"/>
        <echo file="build/utils-src.zip"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="init">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:publish resolver="local">
            <artifacts pattern="build/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </ivy:publish>    
    </target>

</project>
```

ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
            version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.abc" module="utils"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="sources"/>
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="utils" type="jar" conf="default"/>
        <artifact name="utils-src" type="source" ext="zip" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
    </publications>

</ivy-module>
```

### proj2

build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="run">
        <ivy:retrieve/>
    </target>

</project>
```

ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
            version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.abc" module="utils-use"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="sources"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.abc" name="utils" rev="latest.integration" conf="default"/> 
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark. I'll try it when I get to work and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I've tried your example, and it's not quite doing what I wanted. Specifically, in proj2, you need to add `defaultconfmapping="%->default,sources"`. When I do that, however, it all works fine! When I publish and resolve via Artifactory, however, I find that the cached descriptor is as I described (i.e. all the confs apart from default are removed). So I guess this is an Artifactory issue. I'll dig further. Thanks for setting me on the right road!